# Nested For Statement in CMD

Tags: command-line

I am currently having trouble trying to delete some files in a cmd script

I have the following:

```
for /d %%A in (C:\Users\*) do for /d %%B in (%%A\test\*) do echo %%B
```

Although I need to delete the output files, not list them

I have tried:

```
for /d %%A in (C:\Users\*) do for /d %%B in (%%A\test\*) do del %%B
```

But it didnt work

Comment: "did not work" is not helpful. Did it give you an error message? Did it not delete the right files? What was the output?

Comment: Sorry, thanks for you reply, I have just found out that its because of the spaces..

Comment: Found out, just added quotes around %%B

e.g. for /d %%A in (C:\Users\*) do for /d %%B in (%%A\test\*) do del "%%B"

Comment: you should post that as an answer - it's ok to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 1):

Add quotes around `%%B` e.g. for `/d %%A` in (`C:\Users*`) do for `/d %%B` in `%%A\test*` do `del "%%B"`

Comment: Better use `"%%~B"` instead of just `"%%B"`, just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 1):

In addtion to Max's answer you can also use parenthesis to make the batch file easier to read.  You should also use lowercase variable names.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion  

for /d %%a in (C:\Users\*) do (
    rem echo "directory: %%a"
    for /f %%b in ("%%a\test\*") do (
        echo "%%b"
        del "%%b"
    )
)
```